# Changing bottom position with JQuery does not work

Tags: jquery, css

```
var _left = -100;
var isOdd = true;

$(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        //Set Left
        _left += 100;

        if (isOdd) {
            $("#ball").animate({
                top: 0,
                left: _left
            }, 2000);

            isOdd = false;
        }//End of if
        else {
            $("#ball").removeAttr("top")
                .animate({
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: _left
                }, 2000);

            isOdd = true;
        }//End of else
    }, 2000);
});
```

I want to simulate a bouncing ball using JQuery animate instruction.
I want my ball to go 100px left in each bounce.
And as you can see in the code I want my ball to be at the top of the screen in odd moves so to make it feels like that it is bouncing then I shall have my ball at the bottom of the screen in even moves.

The problem is here that the bottom position does not apply.
my ball just keeps moving in a straight line to left while it is stuck in top of screen.

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: That’s probably because you have set `top:0` already, and did not remove that … so it “overrules” `bottom:0`. Try setting `top:auto` together with `bottom:0` in your else branch.

Comment: @CBroe What u r saying is probably right.
But I have tried ur solution and unfortunately , setting top:auto along with bottom:0 does not fix the problem.

Comment: @j08691    https://jsfiddle.net/shahrzadParvizi/mpzg50vr/1/ here is the link to the complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can not animate “between” `top` and `bottom` by setting either property alternately – choose one instead, and animate that between the appropriate maximum and minimum value.

Calculate the maximum top value by subtracting the ball height from the window height beforehand, and then use that value for top in your else branch:

```
var maxTop = $(window).height()-$("#ball").height():
// …

else {
    $("#ball")
        .animate({
            top: maxTop,
            left: _left
        }, 2000);
   isOdd = true;
}//End of else
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mpzg50vr/2/

Comment: It worked!
Thank u.
I used ur solution and I had forgotten to embed the ball in a containing div.
Here is the jsfiddle link, I have updated my BouncingBall jsfiddle and now it is working correctly:
https://jsfiddle.net/shahrzadParvizi/mpzg50vr/4/